# Jetpack Compose Navigation limit of number of Composables to navigate to

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyColumn with multiple elements each goes to new screen via

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
    content = {

        items(tutorialList) { item: TutorialSectionModel ->
            TutorialSectionCard(item) {
                navController.navigate(item.title)
            }
        }
    }
)
```

but when number of screens to navigate to is 13 including start destination i get an error

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=13
        at androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat.valueAt(SparseArrayCompat.java:379)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:948)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:95)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:112)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2422)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:83)
        at com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_1basics.ui.ThemeKt.ComposeTutorialsTheme(Theme.kt:44)
        at com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_1basics.ui.ThemeKt$ComposeTutorialsTheme$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_1basics.ui.ThemeKt$ComposeTutorialsTheme$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2422)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2399)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2580)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2542)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:613)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:764)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:103)
2021-08-23 17:56:29.891 5008-5008/com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_1basics E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:447)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:416)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1008)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:740)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Is this a hard-capped limit, is there a way to overcome this issue for navigation with more than 13 Composables?

If you wish to replicate the issue check out [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/29c884645e74e43de92791dab3d2c50f5d14a9fc/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/MainActivity.kt#L328) and uncomment one of the lines that add tutorials to list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've inspected this issue and it's pretty funny:

It's not crashing on 13 and more composables. It crashing exactly on 13. And also at some random values too like, 29, 61, 125(I stopped checking after that one).

This is already [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195171984) and fixed:

> should be available in the Navigation 2.4.0-alpha08.

And the most interesting to me is [the fix](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1801108/1/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.kt). I still wondering why this code crashes at pretty random counts and works rest of the time.

Anyway, you can just add one more destination and this will work fine.

Comment: This is the funniest bug i have ever encountered. I will check it out and accept the answer. I was at 13th destination and thought it was a hard cap. Good find.